# SSRS 2005 "The report element was not found" html showing when i try to open .rdl

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I just started working with other developers. When they send .rdl files back to me and i try to open the file through visual studio 2005, it shows some raw html rather than the design view.  The html says:

One or more errors encountered while loading the designer. The errors are listed below.
**The Report element was not found.**

How can i fix this?

Comment: what is the schema url in your RDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who has the same problem, I figured it out:

The developers modified and saved using 'Report Builder'(v. 3.0). Report Builder 3.0 is designed to support SSRS 2008 R2 only and supports a new version of the RDL schema, which is not compatible with SSRS 2005. So, i had to use SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services instead.